# Как выровнять картинку по нижней линии родительского блока?

Tags: css

Дорабатываю [сайт](http://ask-carol-com.brandivosites.staging.wpengine.com/), на сайте есть блок с картинкой, которая прижата к низу родительского блока.
[image]

Но при ширине экрана в 1024 пикселей картинка не прижата к нижней линии родительского блока. Как выровнять картинку по нижней линии родительского блока?
[image]

Пробовал так, но не помогло:

```
.post-entry{
        display: table;
    }
    .post-entry .avia-image-container{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так попробуй:

```
.avia-image-container{
    background-image: url(_URL_КАРТИНКИ_);
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```